# Keyword command parameters with table (tabular)

Tags: tables, macros, key-value, xkeyval

I am trying to make a command with named (key-value) parameters to produce a table row. The reason is that table has more than 9 columns (command parameters) that will have position changed, be deleted or added. So it is hard to keep it with regular command (both because positions and limited number of args).

I tried to make it work with [`xkeyval`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval) package, but something gets broken inside table. Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\define@key{myrowkey}{name}{\def\MyRowName{#1}}
\define@key{myrowkey}{num}{\def\MyRowNum{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\myrow[1]{
  \setkeys{myrowkey}{#1}
  \MyRowName, \MyRowNum & \\ \hline
}

\newcommand\myrowb[1]{
  \setkeys{myrowkey}{#1}
  \MyRowName & \MyRowNum \\ \hline
}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
    A & B \\ \hline
    \myrow{name=Abc,num=2000}
    \myrow{name=Def,num=2000}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Command `\myrow` works as I'd like it to, while `\myrowb` does not, i.e., it produces an error. If I replace `\def\MyRowName{...}` with `\newcommand\MyRowName{}` and then `\renewcommand\MyRowName{#1}` there is no error any more, but an empty cell instead of the value (num).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definitions are made within the first cell of the `tabular` and don't survive to the next cell. You need to make their definitions global so they can span multiple columns. If you change `\def` to `\gdef` in the key definitions it will work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\define@key{myrowkey}{name}{\gdef\MyRowName{#1}}
\define@key{myrowkey}{num}{\gdef\MyRowNum{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\myrow[1]{%
  \setkeys{myrowkey}{#1}%
  \MyRowName, \MyRowNum & \\ \hline
}

\newcommand\myrowb[1]{%
  \setkeys{myrowkey}{#1}%
  \MyRowName & \MyRowNum \\ \hline
}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
    A & B \\ \hline
    \myrowb{name=Abc,num=2000}
    \myrow{name=Def,num=2000}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `%` to avoid spurious spaces in your definitions of `\myrow` and `\myrowb`. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Comment: Wow, that was simple :P Thnx!

Comment: @Ivan: Note that this solution will copy elements from one row to the next if it is not specified in the keys. You could add the defaults to the `\setkeys` command within `\myrowb`: `\setkeys{name={},num={},#1}`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. In my full version I have `keyreset` command for this.

Answer (score 3):

Without `\gdef`; this has the advantage that if you need to omit some entry, you just don't set the key (provided you set up at the beginning an empty value for each key).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{myrowkey}{name}{\def\MyRowName{#1}}
\define@key{myrowkey}{num}{\def\MyRowNum{#1}}

\newcommand\myrow[1]{%
  \setkeys{myrowkey}{#1}%
  \begingroup\protected@edef\x{\endgroup
    \MyRowName, \MyRowNum & 
 }\x \\ \hline
}

\newcommand\myrowb[1]{%
  \setkeys{myrowkey}{#1}%
  \begingroup\protected@edef\x{\endgroup
    \MyRowName & \MyRowNum 
  }\x \\ \hline
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
  A & B \\ \hline
  \myrow{name=Abc,num=2000}
  \myrow{name=Def,num=2000}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
  A & B \\ \hline
  \myrowb{name=Abc,num=2000}
  \myrowb{name=Def,num=2000}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to expand the key values before TeX “sees” the `&`.

[image]

The same idea implemented in LaTeX3

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_ivan_row_name_tl
\tl_new:N \l_ivan_row_num_tl
\keys_define:nn { ivan/tab }
 {
  name .code:n    = { \tl_set:Nn \l_ivan_row_name_tl { \exp_not:n { #1 } } },
  name .initial:n = {},
  num  .code:n    = { \tl_set:Nn \l_ivan_row_num_tl { \exp_not:n { #1 } } },
  num  .initial:n = {}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand\myrow{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { ivan/tab } { #1 }
  \use:x
   {
    \l_ivan_row_name_tl,~\l_ivan_row_num_tl
    & 
   }
  \\ \hline
}

\NewDocumentCommand\myrowb{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { ivan/tab } { #1 }
  \use:x
   {
    \l_ivan_row_name_tl & \l_ivan_row_num_tl
   }
  \\ \hline
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
  A & B \\ \hline
  \myrow{name=Abc,num=2000}
  \myrowb{name=\textbf{X}} % no num
  \myrowb{name=Def,num=1}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

As you see, not giving a value will leave the entry empty. Adding keys is made with the same scheme.

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate what do you mean (and how this code achieves it) by "expanding values before TeX sees the '&'". (I roughly understand what happens in my example, but I am not sure that I understand how you circumvent it.)